# How to correctly disable the button based on condition in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to compate initial object and updated object specific values so if they are the same button should be disabled. However it seems even after change button is disabled:

```
  setDisabled(){
  return this.selectedItem.color === this.selectedItemInitial.color &&
  this.selectedItem.price === this.selectedItemInitial.price
  },
```

What is wrong and why it's not changing boolean value?

Answer (score 2):

The function `setDisabled` you defined is executed once when the component is rendered but not when the data in the component changes.

You should move `setDisabled` (and rename it to `buttonDisabled` for clarity) to the computed properties of the component. This way it will get updated when `data` or `props` get updated in the component:

```
computed: {
  buttonDisabled: function(){
        return this.selectedItem.color === this.selectedItemInitial.color && this.selectedItem.price === this.selectedItemInitial.price
   }
}
```

and use it like this in the html:

```
<!-- No parenthesis when using a computed property -->
<button :disabled="buttonDisabled"> ACTION </button>
```

Comment: Can you show how you assign `selectedItem` and `selectedItemInitial`? Vue detect reference changes so you may change the properties of `selectedItem` but not the object itself and Vue wont detect it. I suspect this error

Comment: I assume you are right that is the case and how can be solved in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you instantiate your component data, so its hard to see if there is a logic error.

In general, that method works, if used like this:

```
<button :disabled="setDisabled()"> ACTION </button>
```

also if I suggest you to change it to a computed property instead:

```
computed: {
  setDisabled: function(){
        //logic here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the whole thing in the template. Depending on how the variables are set.

```
<button :disabled="selectedItem.color === selectedItemInitial.color">Click</button>
```